# Please help on using SPSS to add scales of Likert-type

Tags: spss

Since the last post is closed due to unclear expression, here is a edited one.

There are in total 20 items from 5 Likert-type scale questions from a questionnaire. I need to add the 20 items from 5 separate questions to create a total scale. I already got the data.

The question is just like the picture above. How can I run the command to add the 20 items from 5 separate questions? What is the command?

Is it something like Transform > Compute variable. Enter a variable name, specify which items to add up, and hey presto (e.g. "V1+V2+V3" etc)?

Comment: Just add them. Or are you asking about how to add numbers in SPSS?

This is still unclear, and seems to have nothing to do with Likert scale. Nor is it clear why you say 20 items from 5 questions.

Comment: compute scale1 = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5. [new line] execute.  [new line] descriptives scale1.

Comment: Questions solely about how to use your software are appropriate for SO but only rarely here on CV: please see our [faq], which also provides links to other software-specific Web resources.

Answer (score 6):

You can do exactly as you suggested, using the `Transform` -> `Compute variable...` function. Simply type in the name of your new scale in the `Target variable` box and the addition you want in the `Numeric variable` box.

You will see that the following SPSS syntax command is run:

```
COMPUTE total=v1 + v2 + v3 + v4. 
EXECUTE.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If any of the variables has a missing value, the simply adding them will result in a missing value as well. If you don't want to impute for missing values, using the MEAN command in syntax works well. Also, if the variables are contiguous in the data file, you can make the syntax much more readable by using the TO modifier.

```
COMPUTE myscore=MEAN(variable1 TO variable5)*5.
```

The resulting value provides an efficient expected value.

However, it seems like the problem in this case is that the data entry process has dummy coded all of the items, producing 20 separate variables instead of 5, where each block of 4 variables has a value of 0 or 1 but represents the values 1 to 4. In this case, you can use the following syntax:

```
COMPUTE mycounter=1.
COMPUTE myscore=0.
EXECUTE.
DO REPEAT a=variable1 TO variable20.
COMPUTE myscore=myscore+mycounter*a.
COMPUTE mycounter=mycounter+1.
IF (mycounter=5) mycounter=1.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

Note that the variables from variable1 to variable20 must have each set of dummy codes from the original items clustered together in ascending order.